# Avoiding infinite loop with ReactiveVar and Meteor.call inside of withTracker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Currently i'm trying to use Functional StateLess Components as they seem to be much easier to test / mock / keep separate for a StoryBook.

I have started using withTracker in order to integrate React components with Meteor and everything works great when using Meteor.subscribe, for instance:

```
...
module.exports = withTracker( (props) => {
  subscription = Meteor.subscribe( 'posts' )

  loading = subscription.ready()
  posts = Posts.find({}).fetch()

  return {loading, posts}
} )( LowerLevelComponent )
...
```

But sometimes I need to make it Reactive but using a Meteor.call, for instance:

```
...
module.exports = withTracker( (props) => {
  feed = new ReactiveVar(null)

  Meteor.call( 'feed', (error, response) => {

    work = // do some work

    feed.set( work )
  } )

  loading = subscription.ready()
  feed = feed.get()

  return {loading, feed}
} )( LowerLevelComponent )
...
```

The problem here is that every time this component runs the variable "feed" is assigned again to ReactiveVar and the Meteor.call is called again and an infinite loop starts.

---

The only solution i found is to use "feed" as a ReactiveVar out of the Functional Component, for instance:

```
feed = new ReactiveVar(null)
module.exports = withTracker( (props) => {

  if( feed.get() == null ) {
    Meteor.call( 'feed', (error, response) => {

      work = // do some work

      feed.set( work )
    } )
  }

  loading = subscription.ready()
  feed = feed.get()

  return {loading, feed}
} )( LowerLevelComponent )
```

The questions that arises here are:

- What if I navigate through the Router and then come back to this page, will that ReactiveVar still be populated by that value or will the withTracker make sure it's destroyed from memory?
- What if i want to have two components like this but loading different feeds? Would i have to use "dynamic" names for my variables outside of the scope? That seems pretty hacky. I saw some people using `Session` to store those things but that sounds even more hacky.
- Where ideally i would store that ReactiveVar / Meteor.call logic and keep it still belonging to that specific instance of my component?
- Is that what the "state" is all about and I should use some React Component that allows me to setState ? From my poor React experience it looks like it's better no never use state so the code can be easily tested on StoryBook / Jest / Whatever test framework that needs to be used?

By looking at the source code implementation [here](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx) I can see it sends this.props and this.data to the Lower Level Component.. Is this.data the trick? Is that the place where i should add my ReactiveVar so i can Track it and still keep it unique to that instance?

---

After reading @Fred Stark reply:

> So the main issue here is that by using a reactiveVar you are introducing state to the component. This makes functional stateless components a poor choice of pattern to represent what you're trying to do. Try using the class pattern with React.Component for this case

I came to the conclusion that the main issue here ***is not*** that I'm introducing state to the component, but actually the main issue here is how Meteor.call() acts in a different way than Meteor.subscribe().

If adding "state to the function stateless object" was a real issue then `withTracker` function would not make sense all together. Meteor.subscribe() DOES add state to the FSC and that's one of the recommend ways of integrating Meteor data with React as seen on the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker)

After arriving at that conclusion i searched online a bit more and realised there are a few implementations trying to address this issue, such as [meteor-call](https://github.com/mnmtanish/meteor-call) and [ReactiveMethod](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method). Those libraries potentiall will allow me to hide the work-around in a "contained" way and make Meteor.calls work similar to how Meteor.subscribe().

Other option might be to don't use Meteor.call to fetch data even if it won't be reactive, but I'm not 100% sure on the side-effects this could create.

Comment: So the main issue here is that by using a `reactiveVar` you are introducing state to the component. This makes functional stateless components a poor choice of pattern to represent what you're trying to do. Try using the class pattern with React.Component for this case

Comment: @FredStark I really appreciate your reply, it made me think and re-consider a few key-points on this implementation and also find some other solutions, i have edited my question accordingly!

Don't forget my main goal here is just to fetch data and provide it to my LowerLevelComponent which is my 100% stateless UI.

Keeping the HOC as 1 function files help us keep the files small and the project testable, using classes makes mocking and testing much harder at least based on our team experience.

Thank You

Comment: Good point about it not really being state. I'm not really sure of the best solution! Otherwise I would have added an answer myself. These are all excellent questions to ask by the way!

Comment: You can utilize the fact that your current user can have also fields attached. This is how we manage to check if users have already viewed several components or customize their UI in a persistent way. Of course this could be done using a collection but that would introduce a new dependency. Since your user is already a dependency you can stay as flexible and as stateless as possible. I know this is also not a 100% solution but somewhat of a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple days scratching my head with this, I finally found a solution which doesn't damage some of the limitations/rules I'm following in order to have my components compatible and tested on on my website and also on the StoryBook.

The trick was to create a wrapper function which doesn't use withTracker and this function is the one who will hold this "non-reactive" scope while the reactive things happen, all of that with the advantage that all the state is created and destroyed "automatically" ( and hopefully!! ) once my components are removed from the screen.

Instead of:

```
feed = new ReactiveVar(null)
module.exports = withTracker( (props) => {

  if( feed.get() == null ) {
    Meteor.call( 'feed', (error, response) => {

      work = // do some work

      feed.set( work )
    } )
  }

  loading = subscription.ready()
  feed = feed.get()

  return {loading, feed}
} )( LowerLevelComponent )
```

I'm now doing:

```
module.exports = (props) => {

  // NOTE: this will create a ReactiveVar everytime my HOC is created, 
  // without using withTracker.
  feed = new ReactiveVar(null)

  // The "reactive data" will live on my "Intermediary Order Object"
  // which uses withTracker and will be reactive!
  Intermediary = withTracker( (props) => {

    if( feed.get() == null ) {
      Meteor.call( 'feed', (error, response) => {

        work = // do some work

        feed.set( work )
      } )
    }

    loading = subscription.ready()
    feed = feed.get()

    return {loading, feed}
  } )( LowerLevelComponent )

  <Intermediary {...props} />
```